# Where should I ask questions about software industry practices?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm a junior developer trying to find my way. As a part of this I have many questions regarding what other developers have done and what the standard for certain situations is. Unfortunately these kinds of questions aren't always technical with a specific and direct answer, [resulting in my questions being closed on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788129/is-entity-framework-reliable-enough-to-use-in-a-corporate-project-should-i-use).

With this in mind - where can and should I ask these questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about programmers.stackexchange.com?

See the faq for programmers. Some of your questions should fit there.

[Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Although if you post one of your closed SO questions there, you should flag the one on SO so the mods can migrate it and merge the answers.